# macOS Mojave cannot find /var/db/DetachedSignatures with Swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, system, profiler

I had no such error with High Sierra, now with Mojave my application done with Swift 4 is issuing this error. It will happen when I try to get software information by call:
/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType

My application wont fail and works but I notice that it will expose this error when running:

> system_profiler[2052:52918] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:42249: (0) open(/var/db/DetachedSignatures) - Undefined error: 0

I guess it is related to code signatures but I don't know how to handle that, maybe a bug as there isn't any file called DetachedSignatures inside /var/db

Comment: I was able to workaround, not fix, by redirect the output pipe to "nil", so the error messages simply won't appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and I copied the DetachedSignatures file from some other guy's MacBook and put it under /var/db path on my iMac. It solved the problem. Don't know why some mac just don't have this DetachedSignatures file. Not very many useful explanations on the Internet.

Comment: If you do not have access to another laptop, what do you recommend? Can you share the file or point to an example file? I looked into detached signatures and gpg but I don't believe the `--detach-sign` arg to create a `.sig` file is what we need to do here

Comment: Copying some file related to signatures from "some other guy's MacBook"? Yeah, what could possibly go wrong with that.

Comment: John's answer below shall be marked as the correct one.

Comment: It should be, but hasn't yet ...

Answer (score 35):

os_unix.c:37227: (21) seekAndRead(/var/db/DetachedSignatures) - Is a directory

```
sudo touch /var/db/DetachedSignatures
```

This fixed the issue on my machine.

Answer (score 10):

This appears to be logged by the Security framework during some operations; I always see it when my app calls SecKeyGeneratePair. Since everything works correctly I assume this is just noise. (There are other examples of this; the Security engineers at Apple seem to be bad about leaving noisy but harmless log messages in their production code.)

I wouldn't recommend trying to create the DetachedSignatures file! It's clearly used for something by the OS, and just shoving an empty file there, or one copied from elsewhere, could cause problems later on.

Answer (score 3):

I asked someone for their file as @lzl said but they told me the file was 0 bytes. I touched a file at that path and my warnings went away.